# Find the determinant of $I+A$

Tags: determinant

Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix with real entries such that $A^2=0$.Find the determinant of $I+A$ where $I$ denotes the identity matrix. I proceed in this way :Note that $(I+A)A=A+A^2 \Longrightarrow (I+A)A=A$ (Since $A^2=0$).

Now taking determinant both side we get 
$|(I+A)A| = |A| \Longrightarrow |(I+A)|\cdot|A|=|A|\Longrightarrow |I+A|=1$.

Am I proceed in correct way? In the last line am I need to consider $|A|=0$?

Comment: Since $A^2=0$ $A$ is not invertible, therefore $|A|=0$, so your proof is not correct.

Comment: Better consider the characteristic polynomial of $A$. You can compute the one from $A+I$ from it and read out the determinant.

Comment: As an alternative to @sebigu's hint: you can show that a nilpotent matrix is similar to a [*strictly* triangular matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Strictly_triangular_matrix). Now, what is the determinant of the sum of the identity and a strictly triangular matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The matrix $A$ is [nilpotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix) with characteristic polynomial $x^2.$ But by [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Formal_definition) $x^2 = \det(A - xI).$ If we let $x = -1,$ then we have $\det(A + I) = 1.$

Comment: This is the simplest way. Than you for help

Answer (score 12):

$A$ is similar to (and hence has the same determinant as) a matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & * \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. That is, there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that

$$A':=P^{-1}AP = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & * \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and $\det A = \det A'$. But $I':=P^{-1}IP=I$, and so $P^{-1}(I+A)P=I+A'$, and so $\det (I+A) = \det (I+A')$.

So what is $\det (I+A)$?

Answer (score 5):

Let $x = \det (I+A)$

$$(I+A).(I+nA)=I+(n+1)A$$

Hence $\det(I+nA)=x^n$

**But** $\det(I+nA)=P(n)$ with P a polynomial (of maximum degree the size of matrix A).

So the only solutions are $x=1$ or $x=0$. But If $x=0$, there is a $v\neq 0$ such that $v+Av=0$, hence, $Av=-v$, and $A^2v=v$, that is not possible.

So $\det(I+A)=1$

Note that this proof is true for any size of matrix.

Comment: Very nice answer, +1

Answer (score 2):

I like this one:

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x^2$.
By substitution we get
$$(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1$$
as characteristic polynomial of $A+I$. Now we see trace and determinant.

Answer (score 2):

The trace of $A$ is $0$, using $$A^2-\operatorname{tr}(A)\cdot A+(\det A)\cdot I=0$$
and the fact that the determinant of $A$ is $0$. Applying this to $A+I$, we get 
$$\tag{1} A+2I-\operatorname{tr}(A+I)\cdot(A+I)+\det(A+I)\cdot I=0,$$
hence 
$$2A+I-2(A+I)+\det(A+I)\cdot I=0,$$
and $$\det(A+I)\cdot I=I,$$
hence $\det (A+I)$.

The formula $(1)$ can we deduce either by Cayley Hamilton theorem (sledgehammer), or by hand.